# Swagger and Flask, TypeError: Load failed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, cors, swagger

I host a simple website in python with flask and swagger. It works perfectly local and for some reasons when opening the website on my computer, but when I try to run anything on other computers or on my phone, every swagger query leads to the error:

```
TypeError: Load failed
```

Interestingly, running the given example CURL command just returns 301 Moved Permanently.

My code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, jsonify, request, Response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint

from services.HelloWorld import HelloWorld

import json
import datetime
import yaml
from yaml import Loader
from loggenerator import logger
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)

def main():
    # Add the resources to the API
    api.add_resource(HelloWorld, "/dor/helloworld")
    # Configure Swagger UI
    SWAGGER_URL = "/dor"
    API_URL = "/swagger.yaml"
    swaggerui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
        SWAGGER_URL,
        API_URL,
        config={
            "app_name": "Some title"
        }
    )
    app.register_blueprint(swaggerui_blueprint, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)

@app.route("/swagger.yaml")
def swagger():
    with open("swagger.yaml", "r") as f:
        return yaml.load(f, Loader=Loader)

@app.route("/")
def page_index():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeString = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    templateData = {
        "title" : "Myself",
        "time": timeString
    }
    return render_template("index.html", **templateData)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    debug = False
    if debug:
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=56982, debug=True)
    else:
        from waitress import serve
        serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=56981)
```

The example api-command which fails all of the time (among all the others) is HelloWorld.py, looking like this:

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import jsonify
from loggenerator import logger

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            return jsonify({"message": "Hello World"})
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception('An error occurred: %s', e)
```

The swagger config looks like this:

```
basePath: /dor
consumes:
- application/json
info:
  description: Some description
  title: Some title
  version: '1.0'
paths:
  /helloworld:
    get:
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Some description
          schema:
            properties:
              message:
                type: string
            type: object
      summary: Returns greeting message.
produces:
- application/json
schemes:
- http
swagger: '2.0'
```

I was thinking about the question if this might be CORS-related, therefore I also tried to use flask-cors (as seen in the code), but that did not change the outcome.
I also tried to log the error, but interestingly, the catch in the HelloWorld file never actually gets called

Does anybody know what is going on here?